# How to get the message content from a Discord message URL?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Let's say **user x** sends a message in **channel x**. In **channel y**, someone sends the message link of what was said in **channel x** by **user x** and for ease of use, the Discord bot makes an embedded message with the description as the linked message content and such.

For better understanding, please refer to the [image linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9AdH.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the message id within the sent link. After getting the id, you can fetch the message (or get it in the cache), using the [`MessageManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager) accessible from [`TextChannel.messages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=messages) property and display the content.

Here's an example:

```js
const messageLink = <Message>.content;
const messageId = messageLink.split('/')[messageLink.split('/').length - 1]; // The id of the message is in the last position in the link

const resolvedMessage = await <TextChannel>.messages.fetch(messageid);

<TextChannel>.send(resolvedMessage.content);
```

An other solution is to match the link with a regex, and get the id with a group.

```js
const discordLinkReg = /https:\/\/discord\.com\/channels\/\d{18}\/\d{18}\/(\d{18})/g;

const messageId = discordLinkReg.exec(<Message>.content)[1]; // 0 is the link, 1 the first group

const resolvedMessage = await <TextChannel>.messages.fetch(messageid);

<TextChannel>.send(resolvedMessage.content);
```

To get the content of messages for any guild (apart the guilds the bot isn't on) you can use regexes groups, like so:

```js
const discordLinkReg = /https?:(?:www\.)?\/\/discord(?:app)?\.com\/channels\/(\d{18})\/(\d{18})\/(\d{18})/g;
// Make sure the content will always be a discord link.
const parsed = discordLinkReg.exec(someWayToGetContent());
const messageId = parsed[3];
const channelid = parsed[2];
const guildId = parsed[1];
// Or shorter
const [, guildId, channelId, messageId] = discordLinkReg.exec(someWaytoGetContent());

const guild = await <Client>.guilds.fetch(guildId);
const channel = await <Client>.channels.fetch(channelId);
const message = await channel.messages.fetch(messageId);

await channel.send(`Oh, got this: ${message.content}`);
```

Comment: This would only send the message content of a link that is sent from the same channel, let's say the message link was sent from a different channel - this in fact would create an error. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: You can use regexes group, see updated answer, also I upgraded the regex.